# In Excel 2010, how can I convert cells containing "1 day", "2 days" etc to just "1", "2" etc

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

In order to treat them as numbers?

I copied the column from another program which has a list of durations. Unfortunately Excel will not treat these cells as numbers at all so I can't use them in formulas.

I've tried using the Format Cells tool and selecting "Number", but this does not change the cell at all - it still displays "1 day" and formulas referencing it still do not work.

Is there a simple way where a cell value starts with a number and is appended by a string to just get the number value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the column that contains the data.

Press `CTRL+H` to load the find and replace dialogue.

For Find, enter `day` (note the space before the word day)
For Replace, leave empty.
Click on the Replace All button.

This will remove all occurrences of the word ' day' leaving you with your number.

Comment: Advisable to remove `days` first, before `day`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this formula:

```
=IFERROR(VALUE(LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1)-1)),A1)
```

This will try the get the number before any space and convert it into a number.

Comment: Peter, it seems that for SU this is too complicated) Your answer fits SO nicely, my +1.